# Jsoup - cannot select table

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to print out the rows from the table on "https://www.worldcoinindex.com/".  From Chrome's inspect element I can see that the tableID="myTable".  However, when I try to perform the select table method, it returns an Index out of bounds exception.  I am able to print individual rows using the getElementsByClass, so I know it is finding the website.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ParseTable {

    public static void main(String args0[]) throws IOException {
        Document doc;
        Elements elements;

        String url="https://www.worldcoinindex.com/";
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Element table = doc.select("myTable").get(0);      //Select table
        Elements rows = table.select("tr");                // Select tr's
        System.out.println(table.select("tr"));
        for (int j=1; j > rows.size(); j++) {               // Iterate through table data
            System.out.println(rows.get(j).select("td"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>     at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>     at ParseTable.main(ParseTable.java:19)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jsoup, but your for loop looks wrong.

Try starting from 0, and checking if j is less than row.size()

```
for (int j = 0; j < rows.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(rows.get(j).select("td"));
}
```

Comment: Thx for the tip!  Hadn't gotten that far since it is choking on the: Element table = doc.select("myTable").get(0);  statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unlucky all the data is served asynchronously using ajax etc and your scraping happens before this data is even "on the site".

Inspect what you really get as `doc` inside a debugger - which would tell you as much.

If you need stock data, google for APIs - some exist. Search SO as well, there are some threads about it. Maybe https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ would be the better place to ask.

Your error stems from

```
Element table = doc.select("myTable").get(0);
```

You are assuming there *is* an element named "myTable" and access it, if there is not, exception happens. Test select for results before accessing it.

Edit:
If you want to select something by ID, prefix it with `#`:

```
Element table = doc.select("#myTable").get(0);
```

Ypou need to prefix the id by `#` for ids, by `.` for classes.

See: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I mentioned above that I used Chrome's "inspect" utility to confirm the table id=myTable.  I also am able to use Jsoup's method: getElementsByClass to return specific rows of the table - so it seems it would be accessible?  Can someone actually look at the HTML data of the web page and help me confirm I am attacking this the right way?  Should be simple, but for some reason Jsoup is not finding the table.

Comment: @JohnStevens edited, use `Element table = doc.select("#myTable").get(0);`